# Widening long table grouped on date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have run into a problem in transforming a dataframe. I'm trying to widen a table grouped on a datetime column, but cant seem to make it work. I have tried to transpose it, and pivot it but cant really make it the way i want it.

Example table:

```
datetime                      value
2022-04-29T02:00:00.000000000 5
2022-04-29T03:00:00.000000000 6
2022-05-29T02:00:00.000000000 5
2022-05-29T03:00:00.000000000 7
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
index    date         02:00   03:00 
1        2022-04-29   5       6    
2        2022-05-29   5       7
```

The real data has one data point from 00:00 - 20:00 fore each day. So I guess a loop would be the way to go to generate the columns.

Does anyone know a way to solve this, or can nudge me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you only have data at  `02:00` and `03:00` or is it just an example?

Comment: Oh, sorry should have been more concrete. The data has one data point from 00:00 - 20:00. So I guess a loop would be the way to go to generate the columns. Sorry for the diffuse question will add it in the original post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming from details you have provided, I think you are dealing with timeseries data and you have data from different dates acquired at  `02:00:00` and `03:00:00`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

First we replicate your `DataFrame` object.

```
import datetime as dt
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

data_str = """2022-04-29T02:00:00.000000000 5
2022-04-29T03:00:00.000000000 6
2022-05-29T02:00:00.000000000 5
2022-05-29T03:00:00.000000000 7"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), sep=" ", header=None)
df.columns = ["date", "value"]
```

now we calculate unique days where you acquired data:

```
unique_days = df["date"].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x[:-3], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").date()).unique()
```

Here I trimmed last 3 `0`s from your date because it would get complicated to parse. We convert the datetime to `datetime` object and get unique values

Now we create a new empty df in desired form:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "02:00", "03:00"])
```

after this we can populate the values:

```
for day in unique_days:
    new_row_data =  [day] # this creates a row of 3 elems, which will be inserted into empty df
    new_row_data.append(df.loc[df["date"] == f"{day}T02:00:00.000000000", "value"].values[0]) # here we find data for 02:00 for that date
    new_row_data.append(df.loc[df["date"] == f"{day}T03:00:00.000000000", "value"].values[0]) # here we find data for 03:00 same day
    new_df.loc[len(new_df)] = new_row_data # now we insert row to last pos
```

this should give you:

```
         date  02:00  03:00
0  2022-04-29      5      6
1  2022-05-29      5      7
```

Comment: This seems promising, but i got an error "TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable" when running the "unique_days" line. Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: Have you already converted your data to timestamps? If so, you dont need to strip the last three 0's. I assume the error is from `[:-3]` part

Comment: Thanks that worked, but now when i run the for loop i get this error: "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0". Has this something to do with the date column being timestamp?

Comment: which line do you get error in?  here? `new_df.loc[len(new_df)] = new_row_data`

Comment: I get it on "   new_row_data.append(df.loc[df["date"] == f"{day}T02:00:00.000000000", "value"].values[0]) # here we find data for 02:00 for that date"

Comment: That might mean there is no data for 02:00 on that date. Is that possible? That would mean we might need to add try catch to this code.

Comment: I just checked and there is data on the date and time. Is there something with this part? f"{day}T02:00:00.000000000" is it possible to do a "like" statement? since i think that this might be different since the data is in datetime in my df.

Comment: the problem is then we are comparing datetime object to string object which obviously gives `false` and that is why the indexerror. You either need to convert your timestamp back to string before comparision or do something like `df.loc[df["date"] == dt.datetime.strptime(f"{day}T02:00:00.000000","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"), "value"]`